# symfony 2: invoke action inside controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm working on for symfony 2 framework, and i have a problem by invoke a custom Action inside Controller. 
I've connected my app to a database (on xampp), and for each table i have Entity class. Now i've generate a CRUD controller (with doctrine) for one of this entity (GuestController.php), and i need to create a new Action inside it, and invoke it.
this is action code:

```
 /**
 *
 * @Route("/", name="my_action")
 * 
 */
public function customAction() {
    return new Response('<html><body>Hello</body></html>');
}
```

Now if i try to invoke it with this link

```
http://localhost/TEST/web/app_dev.php/guest/guest_search_by_saloon
```

i obtain

```
Unable to find Guest entity.
```

what's wrong?

This is full controller class

```
/**
 * Guest controller.
 *
 * @Route("/guest")
 */
class GuestController extends Controller {

/**
 * Lists all Guest entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="guest")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('mainDbBundle:Guest')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="guest_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("mainDbBundle:Guest:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Guest();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('guest_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Guest entity.
 *
 * @param Guest $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Guest $entity) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new GuestType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('guest_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="guest_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction() {
    $entity = new Guest();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="guest_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('mainDbBundle:Guest')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Guest entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="guest_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('mainDbBundle:Guest')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Guest entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to edit a Guest entity.
 *
 * @param Guest $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createEditForm(Guest $entity) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new GuestType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('guest_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Edits an existing Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="guest_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("mainDbBundle:Guest:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('mainDbBundle:Guest')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Guest entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('guest_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Deletes a Guest entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="guest_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('mainDbBundle:Guest')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Guest entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('guest'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Guest entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
                    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('guest_delete', array('id' => $id)))
                    ->setMethod('DELETE')
                    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
                    ->getForm()
    ;
}

/**
 *
 * @Route("/", name="guest_search_by_saloon")
 * 
 */
public function getBySaloonAction() {
    return new Response('<html><body>Ciao !</body></html>');
}
```

}

this is what log says:

```
NFO - Matched route "guest_show" (parameters: "_controller": "main\dbBundle\Controller\GuestController::showAction", "id": "guest_search_by_saloon", "_route": "guest_show")
```

Comment: You need to show us whole controller. From what I can see there, it doesn't seems that this is your full code. Or, at least, you should include the right action (your route doesn't correspond to what you're calling with your browser)

Comment: i've edited my answer with full controller code

Comment: Is `indexAction()` called somehow?

Comment: yes, as i can see, it's called when i open page with link  http://localhost/TEST/web/app_dev.php/guest/

Comment: No, ok, I know that but you're telling us that for `http://localhost/TEST/web/app_dev.php/guest/guest_search_by_saloon` error is what you shown. Is correct?

Comment: Could you log `indexAction` after calling url you give us? To me code is breaking there, but if you say that routing leads to last action of your controller, I can't understand the error anymore.

Comment: i've add log on my question

Comment: what you get if you change getBySaloonAction
/**
 *
 * @Route("/search", name="guest_search_by_saloon")
 * 
 */
And call it from http://localhost/TEST/web/app_dev.php/guest/search

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my guess is that first of all you're not calling url you're showing us because, as logs says, `showAction()` is called instead of `getBySaloonAction()` and this, related to your error, is perfectly sensible.

If you notice log error, you're passing `guest_search_by_saloon` (string) as `id` (integer) somehow and db query is run with `$id = 'guest_search_by_saloon'` and this lead you to error.

Comment: so showAction is called automatically? because i don't know why it's called, with my link i just want to call getBySaloonAction

Comment: @giozh: maybe you're messing up something with routes. Have to, perchance, a routing.yml file somewhere?